# phonegap cordova camera fail

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I follow [the Documentations](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html). I already added all the plugins.

```
cordova plugin add git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
cordova plugin add git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git
cordova plugin add git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

I put in the config and the manifest relevant all the permissions.

config:

```
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
```

manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
```

I even copied the html page from the documentation and nothing!! the camera in me cell phone not work!

I build my project like that:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova build
```

Please anyone know what the problem ?

**Edit**

Error Logs:

```
14:10:55 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure  
14:12:30 IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
14:12:30 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure 
14:12:33 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure
```

RESOLVED
i had an old version of cordova.

Comment: Please post your error logs.

Comment: You're reading the docs of a very old version of phonegap. You should start by reading the latest docs : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/dev/doc/index.md

Comment: my android studio event log is the follow: 14:10:55 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure
14:12:30 IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
14:12:30 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure
14:12:33 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure

Comment: let me know if you got problem with that so I can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

remove all this line in your config.xml

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
```

Replace with this one

```
<feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
```